# Find tangent plane parallel to $x+y+z=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, tangent-spaces

> Given surface defined by $2x^2+3y^2+z^2=\frac{13}{6}$ parallel to the plane $x+y+z=1$. Find the tangent plane corresponding to it. The intersection of the plane and the surface happens in the first quadrant.

I found the normal of the surface as <4x,6y,2z> and equated it to the normal of the plane $x+y+z=1$ and got value of x in terms of a constant k and plugged it in the equation of the surface to get k and thus values x,y and z.

But here I am getting k as irrational and the calculation is becoming complex and lengthy.

Can you please let me know if my approach to the above formulation is correct or suggest a better way for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching the two normals
$$4x:6y:2z=1:1:1$$
or, $y=\frac23x$ and $z=2x$. Then, substitute them into
$2x^2+3y^2+z^2=\frac{13}{6}$ to get
$$2x^2 +3(\frac23 x)^2+(2x)^2=\frac{13}6$$
which leads to the tangent point $(
\frac12\sqrt{\frac{13}{11}},\frac13\sqrt{\frac{13}{11}}, \sqrt{\frac{13}{11}})$. Then, the tangent plane is
$$(1,1,1)\cdot\left(x-\frac12\sqrt{\frac{13}{11}},
y-\frac13\sqrt{\frac{13}{11}}, z-\sqrt{\frac{13}{11}}\right)=0
$$
which is
$$x+y+z= \frac{\sqrt{143}}6$$

Comment: thanks i tried using it to get the tangent plane x+By+Cz=D but the calculations are coming in irrational form

Comment: @tendo - please see the edit

Comment: thanks had a query here we did a dot product with the parallel plane normal vector and the tangent. Can we do the do the same with the normal to the surface 2x^2+3y^2+z^2=13/6?

Comment: @tendo - you could. But at the tangent point, the two normals are equal and you would get the same result

Comment: Got it thank you